# Why passing parameters to anon function when creating scoping

Tags: javascript, scope

Sorry, the title sucks but I couldn't think of a better one.

The ShadowDOM.js file in Polymer does this:

```
(function(scope) {
  "use strict";
  var unsafeUnwrap = scope.unsafeUnwrap;
  var wrap = scope.wrap;
  var nonEnumDescriptor = {
    enumerable: false
  };
  function nonEnum(obj, prop) {
    Object.defineProperty(obj, prop, nonEnumDescriptor);
  }
  function NodeList() {
    this.length = 0;
    nonEnum(this, "length");
  }
  NodeList.prototype = {
    item: function(index) {
      return this[index];
    }
  };
  nonEnum(NodeList.prototype, "item");
  function wrapNodeList(list) {
    if (list == null) return list;
    var wrapperList = new NodeList();
    for (var i = 0, length = list.length; i < length; i++) {
      wrapperList[i] = wrap(list[i]);
    }
    wrapperList.length = length;
    return wrapperList;
  }
  function addWrapNodeListMethod(wrapperConstructor, name) {
    wrapperConstructor.prototype[name] = function() {
      return wrapNodeList(unsafeUnwrap(this)[name].apply(unsafeUnwrap(this), arguments));
    };
  }
  scope.wrappers.NodeList = NodeList;
  scope.addWrapNodeListMethod = addWrapNodeListMethod;
  scope.wrapNodeList = wrapNodeList;
})(window.ShadowDOMPolyfill);
```

Simple question: why passing the parameter `window.ShadowDOMPolyfill`?

Yes, this is an anonymous function that gets executed straight away. Yes all of the variables will stay within the function, avoid pollution. Yes `scope` will be the same as `window.ShadowDOMPolyfill`.

This is a pattern I have seen many times. I totally understand why it's good not to pollute the global scope with variables, etc. But, why passing  window.ShadowDOMPolyfill as first parameter? As far as I know, the Window object is totally available within functions... so  what's the difference between the code above and:

```
(function() {
  "use strict";
  var scope = window.ShadowDOMPolyfill;
  ...
})();
```

...?

Comment: My guess: personal preference.

Comment: Cleaner looking API. Maybe a tiny bit of a performance boost. But functionally speaking, they both do the same thing.

Comment: Wow... I didn't expect this. I seriously expected that I had missed some huge parts of Javascript even though I have written a lot of code (it would't be the first time!)

Comment: Looks cleaner, encloses the variable so it's not easily overwritten outside the IIFE, easier to minimize for libraries that does that etc. especially as `window.property` won't be minimized, but `scope` will.

Comment: "looks cleaner" -- hummmm OK. "it's not easily overwritten outside the IIFE" -- why would it be harder to overwrite it ouside the IIFE? "easier to minimise" -- why? I would _love_ to see this as an answer, once it's a little expanded...

Answer (score 4):

It's considered good practice to define the parameters your function needs in order to do the work it's assigned to do, in the argument list.

While it's perfectly possible to do it the way you propose, it encourages a **lying API**, in a sense that you can't look at the function signature and understand what goes into the function.

In this **particular** instance, the two examples are identical in functionality, however, imagine there being more parameters, and their usages and definitions are scattered across the function body.

```
(function(oneThing, anotherThing, aThirdThing) {
  ...
})(window.oneThing, window.anotherThing, window.aThirdThing);
```

is more readable than

```
(function() {
  ... // with your vars somewhere inside.
})();
```

In your example, you must enforce a convention with your developers to always put these definitions at the top, to maintain readability. However, the language *already* helps you enforce that with the argument list.

Comment: I like this perspective on it a lot.

Comment: It's also a better fit for an answer to the full question (than mine was).

Answer (score 2):

Another possible reason is that it makes testing easier, and more compatible with other environments. Angular has a similar approach as they recommend to use the variable $window instead of window although they have the same value.

A simple example:

```
function myFunction(globalContext) {
   //adding stuff to the global object
}

myFunction(window || myGlobalObject)
```

This function can receive as parameter `window`, a `mocked window`, or a totally different global object in Nodejs, Rhino or Nashorn engines (not browser environments)